# OpenLayers zoom style like GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

In `GoogleMaps` when users zooms In/Out using mouse wheel the point under cursor stays the same (its coordinates), but `OpenLayers` map has different approach - when zooming center of the map is constant. Can one use `GoogleMaps` zoom style in `OpenLayers` map?

EDIT:
Actually current behaviour in my `OpenLayers` is that when I zoom in with some position under the cursor it moves that position to map center on the next zoom level. Probably it is some issue related to my map specific settings (like projection).

Comment: Are you asking of red box in google maps which appears when dragged until new tile is loaded ?

Comment: Do you have a link to try it out? I use projected data and I don't experience the issue you are describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults control for navigation. Well, you shouldn't, because this control is replaced with OpenLayers.Control.Navigation and will be deprecated in OpenLayers 3.0.

A quick look at source code for MouseDefaults shows that it definitely centers map on the cursor position:

```
defaultWheelDown: function(evt) {
    if (this.map.getZoom() > 0) {
        this.map.setCenter(this.map.getLonLatFromPixel(evt.xy),
                           this.map.getZoom() - 1);
    }
},
```

While cursor stays at the same position the map will centered to new location every time you zoom in/out, which is confusing.

OpenLayers.Control.Navigation uses the same approach as Google Maps. OpenStreetMap uses it and you can see that it works the same way [here](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when looking at the [Basic Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/example.html) at OpenLayers, it seems like the map zooms around the mouse pointer, just as Google Maps does. Or am I missing some detail in your question?

Comment: Yes, your are right but in my case it doesn't work. I add some details to question description to explain my current situation.